# Найти значение «текущая дата - 31 день» в миллисекундах?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Найти значение «текущая дата - 31 день» на сервере в милиссекундах? Лучше с использованием  date-fns библиотеке

Comment: В чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const date = new Date(); // текущая дата
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 31); // -31 день
console.log(+date); // в миллисекундах
```